# Exporting image chips using training sample in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, deep-learning

I'm exporting the training samples to the correct format as image chip using "Export Training Data for Deep Learning" tool in arcgis pro. The Images chips normally should be the JPEG format according the trainig sample created but The results in my case  are a folder representing  image chips of all the drone images. The tool is not taking in consideration the training sample.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.